# multiple condtion in defining a variable - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this array `$node_actions` :

```
Array
(
    [new] => yes
    [fav] => no
    [eye] => no
    [edit] => yes
    [delete] => yes
)
```

And sometimes it comes mince some element( like `new` or `eye` for example).So I need to define a variable that has this actions:

```
$actions = $new.' '.$fav.' '.$eye.' '.$edit.' '.$delete;
```

Here's how I do it :

```
if(!isset(($node_actions['new'])){
    $actions =$fav.' '.$eye.' '.$edit.' '.$delete;
}elseif(!isset(($node_actions['fav'])){
    $actions =$new.' '.$eye.' '.$edit.' '.$delete;
}elseif(!isset(($node_actions['eye'])){
    $actions =$new.' '.$fav.' '.$edit.' '.$delete;
}elseif(!isset(($node_actions['edit'])){
    $actions =$new.' '.$fav.' '.$eye.' '.$delete;
}elseif(!isset(($node_actions['delete'])){
    $actions =$new.' '.$fav.' '.$eye.' '.$edit;
}elseif(!isset(($node_actions['new']) && !isset(($node_actions['new']) ){
    $actions =$eye.' '.$edit.' '.$delete;
}else{

} //.... and so on
```

is there an elegant easy way to do the same ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Just curious: Are we looking at some kind of boolean-based authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing:

```
$actions = "";
foreach($yourArr as $key => $val) {
  $actions .= $$key. " ";
}
$actions = trim($actions);
```

Comment: its $$key, i.e variable from value

Answer (score 1):

try with loop

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if(!empty($v)) {
    $actions .= $v.' ';  // yes no no yes yes 
    //$actions .= $k.' '; //new fav eye edit delete 
  }
}
echo $actions;
```

Answer (score 1):

i prefer this approach in this 
        $new    = 1;
    $fav    = 2;
    $eye    = 4;
    $edit   = 8;
    $delete = 16; are variables bound to some specific task and they are matched to some variable ($action in this case ) coming from GET or POST

```
<?php

$new    = 1;
$fav    = 2;
$eye    = 4;
$edit   = 8;
$delete = 16;


$action = $fav | $eye; // OR $fav | $eye | $delete OR $new

if($action & $new) {
    echo "new";
} 

if($action & $fav) {
    echo "fav";
} 

if($action & $eye) {
    echo "eye";
} 

if($action & $edit) {
    echo "edit";
} 

if($action & $delete) {
    echo "delete";
} 

?>
```

Hope this will help you